# How do I start a server via ssh and have it run after I log out?

Tags: ssh, process, process-management

I ssh into a virtual server and start up a web server. Everything runs as expected. But when I close my terminal on my laptop, the process dies on the virtual server. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **disown**, it is a bash builtin:

> disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]
>
> Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active
>   jobs. If the -h option is given, each jobspec is not removed from the
>   table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the
>   shell receives a SIGHUP. If no jobspec is present, and neither the -a
>   nor the -r option is supplied, the current job is used. If no jobspec
>   is supplied, the -a option means to remove or mark all jobs; the -r
>   option without a jobspec argument restricts operation to running jobs.
>   The return value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.

Try this:

```
$ <your command> &
$ disown
```

First, make your command run in background by typing `<your command> &`, then use `disown`, it will make your command keep running even if your ssh session is disconnected.

IMHO, you should use a tool to control your service, like `supervisord` or writing your own init script.

Comment: what does the ampersand do in the $command & line? Do I type the ampersand?

Comment: Yes, type `<your command> &` make your program running in background.

Comment: I should add, that stopping that service is a bit difficult with `ps` and killing the right PID. It might be a good idea to save that PID with `echo $! > server.pid`, so it's easier to stop a process just by using that PID.

Comment: Why is it difficult to stop with `ps`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with httpd on a systemd based system -

When logged into the server, you should run these commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable httpd.service
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

You can check to see if it is running on subsequent logins by running this command:

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of two things:

- Redirecting the standard input/output streams to/from nowhere.
- Forking the process into the background *reparented by init*.

The "reparented by init"<sup>1</sup> bit is the most crucial part, since otherwise the process will receive a [HUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP#SIGHUP) when you log out.  The `nohup` command can block the HUP, and the now orphan process will then be adopted by init, but a better solution is simply to use `setsid`, which immediately starts the process in a new [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group), with init as its parent:

```
setsid myprog < /dev/zero 2>&1&> /dev/null
```

`< /dev/zero` redirects stdin; this may or may not matter depending on the nature of `myprog`.  `2>&1&> /dev/null` redirects output so that you don't get any junk on your terminal before you log out.

---

<sup>1. Init is the first process started on the system (by the kernel) and the only one that cannot die.  The PID of init is always 1.  Note that some systems use an init daemon with a different executable name, you can identify it with `ps -p 1`.</sup>