# Let users create their own daemons

Tags: non-root-user, daemon

How do I let server's users create their own daemons? They should auto-start on boot and otherwise behave just like regular daemons but with lower privileges overall.

I remember I saw a tool that let a user create a file in format similar to a crontab one with his wishes. The tool made sure the programs from the file would *be running at all times*. But now just couldn't find it's name.

`nohup ./app &` just doesn't cut because it is won't autostart and the app won't restart automatically. Same as `@reboot` in user's `crontab`.

The thing is that I don't want to reinvent a wheel. If there is something that does what I want in full, I would use it. And only if there is nothing, I would fall back to a hand-made approach.

(I am using Debian stable, so I don't have systemd yet, as far as I understand.)

Comment: *"I remember I saw a tool that let a user create a file in format similar to a crontab one"* -- you could use crontab for individual users here (see `man crontab`); just schedule a check to see if the process is running every minute or so.  Note that `nohup ./app &` does not really daemonize a process -- see [here for a better idea](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118753/how-do-i-start-a-server-via-ssh-and-have-it-run-after-i-log-out/118757#118757).

Comment: " *Everyone has his own daemon* " old popular thoughts

Comment: @goldilocks sure, if I wouldn't find anything feasible, sure I'll make up something to manage clients' processes. My question is that is there is something already done on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the home directories for the users are accessible early (before cron starts) and have them make an entry in crontab:

```
@reboot /home/username/bin/start_at_boot
```

This is [a standard feature of a cron daemon](http://www.unixdaemon.net/linux/how-does-cron-reboot-work/) which should be on your Debian system.

The `start_at_boot script` can start the users daemons directly, or start some tool that manages and watches the users' daemons (the configuration for which can be under the control of the individual user). I have used several packages for this, e.g. `procer` that comes with [mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/). But now tend to use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) (being in python makes it easier to understand and extend once the need for that arises).

For other scheduling (or kicking a dormant daemon into activity) the users can make normal entries in their own crontab.

Comment: `@reboot` option won't restart a failed process. And yes, I am looking for a tool that manages and watches the users` daemons you're mentioning.

Comment: @sanmai I extended the answer, procer is real simple but not much used. supervisor is more powerful, but still simple to maintain. Use its `-c` option in the crontab to read a per user specific config file, or use a system wide script that does so and tell the users to put that script in their crontab after `@reboot`

Comment: I ended up using supervisor, still not allowing users add their own daemon on their own - they'll need to ask an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on systemd, it's trivial, because systemd doesn't require the "fork/exec/pidfile" formalism. You just create a service file and systemd takes care of starting the process, restarting a crashed instance and so on. You can also easily allow users to create their own service files (or even run them not as root but as their own user - if that's useful somehow).

On system V initscripts, the most standard way is to start them in `/etc/rc.local`. Automatic restarting doesn't usually work even for system daemons! You could however write a shell wrapper that runs the process in a loop (possibly with a sleep 1 to avoid problems with constantly failing processes). However in this system, you have very little control over individual daemons.

You could also just create initscripts and put them in a special user-accessible directory in rc.d and modify the service starting system.